# Represent one to many relationship on one report and get the many-table in a row instead of col

Tags: sql

My user wants a report which rows and columns of many-table repeats in a single row until all rows of many-table are finished.
what is the best way to write query for that?
i hope could get what i want

```
______________________________________________________________________________________
|table(1)       |                table(2)                                             |
|---------------|--------------------|--------------------|------|--------------------|
|table(1) (row1)|table(2 of 1)(row 1)|table(2 of 1)(row 2)| .... |table(N of 1)(row X)|
|---------------|--------------------|--------------------|------|--------------------|
|table(1) (row2)|table(2 of 2)(row 1)|table(2 of 2)(row 2)| .... |table(N of 2)(row y)|
|---------------|--------------------|--------------------|------|--------------------|
|table(1) (row3)|table(2 of 3)(row 1)|table(2 of 3)(row 2)| .... |table(N of 3)(row Z)|
|---------------|--------------------|--------------------|------|--------------------|
...
...
...
```

Comment: I don't really understand... Can you give an example with some real data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the tools you need:

1. Dynamic SQL
2. nested queries
3. `rownum` function
4. `case when`

If possible, I would load the data from the database to your front end and change the representation there.